# Javascript popup selector from Child to Parent Window

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have a problem here. Whenever i try to change the text field value by clicking the button from the child window... it is not working.

Parent window

```
<html> 
<script language="javascript"> 
function openWindow() { 
  window.open("target.html","_blank","height=200,width=400, status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no") 
} 
</script> 
<body> 
<form name=frm> 
<input id=text1 type=text> 
<input type=button onclick="javascript:openWindow()" value="Open window.."> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Child window which is the  target.html

```
<html> 
<script language="javascript"> 
function changeParent() { 
  window.opener.document.getElementById('text1').value="Value changed.." 
} 
</script> 
<body> 
<form> 
<input type=button onclick="javascript:changeParent()" value="Change opener's textbox's value.."> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

What i really want to happen is when I click the button from child window... the child window will be closed and then the text field in a parent window will be changed into "Change opener's textbox's value.." which is the value that Ive chosen from child window..

Comment: Why do you want to open a brand new window? Why not create a popup DIV with the functionality you need?

Comment: This is the only way that i know. How can I have a popup chooser that will go directly in a certain field.

Comment: your code should be working in firefox, I think it must not be working in chrome?

Comment: What could be the problem in chrome? Do you have any suggestions in doing this thing in all browsers?

Comment: this is a issue in chrome http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116729. Please vote for the issue if you want to see it fixed

Comment: I suggest you look at lightbox or fancybox. So, it will be a <div> in your current page itself that appears like a popup and you can easily use the value using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is basically restricted to the window. You can't just send values to another window (that would be cool).

There are ways for parent and child  windows to communicate to eachother but there are some cross browser issues:
http://www.codehappiness.com/post/access-parent-window-from-child-window-or-access-child-window-from-parent-window-using-javascript.aspx

The easiest solution would not be to open a new window but a modal box within the same window. This is nothing more then a div that is styled to appear as a popupbox. The easiest way for a noob to make this is probaply using the jquery ui modal feature.

Good luck!!

Comment: Fancybox is wonderfull btw, a lot smaller then the jquery ui.